# How to add Facebook, twitter, mail, message icons in UIactivityviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios6

Have added activityviewcontroller to the main controller

```
-(void)ActionSheet2:(id)sender
{
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] init];

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact ];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

[activityViewController release];
}
```

When i hit actionsheet button it shows blank activityviewcontroller with only cancel button. How can i now add Facebook, twitter, email and iMessage as share services in activityviewcontroller.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
     //Include an array of things being attached to the ActivityViewController
     //The Array cannot be nil, you must provide something. Either an image or text or both
      NSArray *activityItems = @[@"Hello",[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"]];
      UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
      activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact ];    
       [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];      
       [activityViewController release];
```

Comment: do i have to add Facebook app id and secret key

Comment: You have to make sure you are logged into Facebook on the device using Settings-->Facebook

Comment: @shabzco, though I am not logged into Facebook on my iPhone, I can see facebook icon from the Apple camera app image sharing UIActivityViewController. And I can see Message icon when sharing image. Do you know how can the facebook icon is shown?

Comment: @ttotto: Apple only allows the facebook icon to be shown in its native applications when you are not logged. Your best bet is to customize the dialog box.