# UIActivityViewController with Text and Mail only

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'd like to create a `UIActivityViewController` with just the text and mail activities. How would I do this? The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) seems to be fairly sparse in substance.

I'm using the following code to present my `UIActivityViewController`:

```
NSArray *Items   = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"text"];

UIActivityViewController *ActivityView =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc]
 initWithActivityItems:Items applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:ActivityView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to set `setExcludedActivityTypes` like this:-

```
[ActivityView setExcludedActivityTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                               UIActivityTypeMail,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,nil]];
```

Comment: also, I don't know if you noticed, but the message system icon doesn't appear. Is that just because I'm testing this on the iOS simulator?

Comment: take a look this documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html and also check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606444/how-to-add-facebook-twitter-mail-message-icons-in-uiactivityviewcontroller

Comment: Test app in Device as mention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910366/what-is-the-bundle-identifier-of-apples-default-applications-in-ios