# how to display native share icons in actionsheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In iOS 7 I want to share something it brings up an action sheet similar to this:

[image]

my code is:

```
NSString *textToShare = @"your text";
UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
NSArray *itemsToShare = @[textToShare, imageToShare];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]; //or whichever you don't need
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But i'm getting blank like this:

[image]

Comment: check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961932/uiactivityviewcontroller-with-text-and-mail-only/17961998#17961998

Comment: It's working but i'm getting only copy. i want to get facebook,twitter,mail and message. @NitinGohel

Comment: Did you try this on an actual device rather on a simulator? Note that some of those apps aren't there on the simulator. If you have test in a device (and it has Facebook, twitter installed), then it will show up in the activityviewcontroller.

Comment: yes. I tested this sample in device. That device have facebook and twitter apps. But there is also i'm getting only copy.

Comment: Make sure imageToShare is not nil

Comment: imageToShare is not nil. now i'm getting "save image", "Assign to contact" and "copy".

Comment: Are you logged in, via the `settings app`, on twitter and facebook? Because just having the app installed makes not differance, you need to login via the `settings.app`

Comment: `[activityVC setExcludedActivityTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                            UIActivityTypeMail,UIActivityTypeMessage,UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,nil]];` I'm using this code.

Comment: yes. I logged in twitter and facebook via settings. @rckoenes

Comment: You may have to transform the image to `NSData`?

Comment: @Goutham in the code you posted you excluded twitter and facebook:`UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivity‌​TypePostToTwitter` thus they will not show up.

Comment: so now what i will do. how to post to twitter and facebook via UIActivityViewController.

Comment: Don't include the service your want in the array that you set in the `setExcludedActivityTypes:`. This is an array of activity types you **don't** want to be available, aka excluded.